# Dokeos warning: Strict Standards

Tags: php, warnings, standards, strict

When installing dokeos 2.1 into htdocs, it shows warnings like these:

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of SortableTableFromArray::get_table_data() should be compatible with that of SortableTable::get_table_data() in ...\dokeos\main\inc\lib\sortabletable.class.php on line 989

Strict Standards: Declaration of SortableTableFromArrayConfig::get_table_data() should be compatible with that of SortableTable::get_table_data() in ...\dokeos\main\inc\lib\sortabletable.class.php on line 1032
```

and about ten same warnings like this:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in ...\dokeos\main\inc\lib\internationalization.lib.php on line 203
```

How to solve this?

Comment: If there's a newer version then try upgrading to it.

Comment: dokeos should be entirely rewrite... spaghetti code rules... if you really want to use it you should disable display_error in your php conf

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to php.ini check if `error_reporting` option includes E_STRICT error level. If so, remove it. If you don't have access to php.ini add `error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_STRICT);` in your application code (ex. main PHP entry file).

Comment: is it safe for removing error reporting? Could it work perfectly as normal?

Comment: @bagz_man You're only removing E_STRICT messages from your error reporting which are rather suggestions not real errors. As documentation says: `STRICT messages will help you to use the latest and greatest suggested method of coding, for example warn you about using deprecated functions.`